# Python: Need a hint on extracting blocks of data from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract block of  columnar data which is repeatable(blocks) in a file wherever "Stresses in quadrilateral elements are there"block of data is repeated.Following is the code which i have tried but i am getting error "Index out of range" then i want skip the text in middle of the file .i want only columnar data.

```
Error:

L.append('%s\t %s\t %s\n' %(line[1],line[2],line[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range

import os
f1=open('newdata1.txt','w')
file=open('plate.f06')
L = []
while True:
  line=file.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  if 'S T R E S S E S   I N   Q U A D R I L A T E R A L   E L E M E N T S ' in line:

    print line

 for index, line in enumerate(file):
    if index < 1: #skip first 5 lines
        continue
    else:

      line =line.split()
      L.append('%s\t %s\t %s\n' %(line[1],line[2],line[3]))
f1.writelines(L)

f1.close()
```

File looks like this

```
S T R E S S E S   I N   Q U A D R I L A T E R A L   E L E M E N T S   ( Q U A D 4 )           
OPTION = BILIN  
ELEMENT          FIBER     STRESSES IN ELEMENT COORD SYSTEM  PRINCIPAL STRESSES (ZERO    
SHEAR)             
ID      GRID-ID  DISTANCE  NORMAL-X NORMAL-Y SHEAR-XY ANGLE  MAjor MINOR VON MISES 

121      3423      342        4545     45435    4345   42353  56456 67658   3435
```

Comment: When do you get the exception? Can you share the error log?

Comment: This line confuses me. `if index < 1: #skip first 5 lines` Looks like it skips one line to me.

Comment: There are lines with only one or two words in them. Try printing them before the error. (maybe also only spaces. try `print repr(line)`.)

Comment: Arkocal,If i copy a single block of data(as shown above)into a new file and run a code.it is running fine.If i run this code for entire file which has so repeated blocks like this ,then it is throwing an error.what do i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but better late than never !

The standards have now switched to Python 3 so that's what I will use to update the code :

```py
import os

f1 = open("newdata1.txt", "w")
file = open("plate.f06")
L = []
while True:
    # Ensure that a line with only spaces will not count as containing information
    line = file.readline().strip()
    if not line:
        break
    if "S T R E S S E S   I N   Q U A D R I L A T E R A L   E L E M E N T S " in line:
        print(line)

for index, line in enumerate(file):
    # I disabled this for the sake of the example which did not contain any extra lines
    if index < 0:  # skip first X lines
        continue
    # Else is not needed here
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) < 4: # You want the first 4 columns to be present to avoid the error
        continue
    # Always be sure to check for the length of your list if you use user-provided inputs (the file here)
    L.append("%s\t %s\t %s\n" % (line[1], line[2], line[3]))
f1.writelines(L)

f1.close()
```

Always check if the format your expected was received : here you need the correct number of columns. Another sanity check would be to check the header to see if it has the right headers to prevent a subtle change in the column order from breaking your code without you knowing it.